# Style of Section Headings in LNCS

Tags: sectioning, document-classes, lncs

I am using the LNCS-Style, documentsclass llncs and there is no possibilty to use chapters. Actually when adding a section it looks some kind of this:

[image]

What i want to do is to change just the style of this main sections and leave any other nested sections below alone (subsections, subsubsections, paragraphs ...). It should look some kind of this:

[image]

What i tried was renewing the section command by doing this:

```
\renewcommand{\thesection}{Chapter \arabic{section}}
```

That was the only thing that came in my mind but this actually not what i need, as it only adds a text before the section number and affects even the subsections and every section below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>`llncs.cls` is downloadable at ftp://ftp.springernature.com/cs-proceeding/llncs/llncs2e.zip</sub>

With `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\let\subparagraph\relax

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thesection}{20pt}{\Huge}

\begin{document}
\section{a section}
Some text
\subsection{a subsection}
Some text again
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the line

```
\let\subparagraph\relax
```

needed otherwise `titlesec` can't be loaded.

Comment: @Caffeine You're welcome, happy to help.

Comment: Awesome! How did you know that you need to put this line?